# How to sort data in table

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
m = matrix(c(c(1,4,2,5,8,5)), ncol=2)
colnames(m)<-c("a", "b")
```

so I have:

```
     a b
[1,] 1 5
[2,] 4 8
[3,] 2 5
```

How to sort for example by column **a**?

Comment: `m[order(m[,"a"]),]`?

Comment: @nrussell IMO you should post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `base::order`:

```
R> m[order(m[,"a"]), ]
#     a b
#[1,] 1 5
#[2,] 2 5
#[3,] 4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dplyr` package. But this change to a data.frame... but you can easily change it back

```
#install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
M <- arrange(as.data.frame(m), a) 
#change back
m <- as.matrix(M)
```